# Client Credential Flow in power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector, clientcredential

We want to call 3rd party API, the 3rd party API follow the Client Credential flow as per this document:-

https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/client-credentials-flow

so how we can call this API inside our Power Automate flow? i tried to create a custom connector, but seems custom connectors does not support Client Credential flows.. any advice?

Thanks

Comment: As long as there's no user interaction required, is there any reason why you can't just use the HTTP/Request connector to make the relevant calls?

Comment: @Skin it will over complicate the process, i need to create the custom connector and send it to our clients so they can interacts with the 3rd party API. the flow might have 5-6 action to call the external APIs.. so doing this using Http/Request will not allow us to reuse the process

Comment: Oh ok, sorry, I misunderstood, it looked like you tried to create a custom connector to overcome your issue, I wasn't aware that the custom connector was a part of the intended solution for 3rd parties.

Comment: I've never created a custom connector but looking at it, you can write code, does this not help?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/define-blank#step-4-optional-use-custom-code-support

Answer (score 0):

currently it is not possible to use grant type client credentials in custom connectors.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/connection-parameters
To realize a Power Automate flow with client credentials you need to use the http connector. Here you can specify the client credentials:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COax2.png)